# How to get Hangfire job scheduler to stagger my 20 minute interval jobs

Tags: c#, cron, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

I have a number of tasks that i need run every 20 minutes. I can achieve this in Hangfire using the cron expression `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => /* my method */, "*/20 * * * *")`

The problem with this is, all my tasks will end up running at exactly the same time e.g. 00:00, 00:20, 00:40, 01:00

Does anyone know of a way to stagger one's 20 minute interval tasks without implementing some sort of manual intervention?

I'd just like Hangfire to run the jobs every 20 minutes from the time I create them, nothing too special :)

Comment: I think it's a real shame there isn't built in support for this. I don't want things all running at the same time because they're likely to hit the same database tables and maybe cause deadlocks. Sure I can fix them but I'd just feel a lot more comfortable being able to stagger jobs. Even if it just executed things in series that were due to run at the same 'cron time'. Wondering if attributes can be used for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try this: First, modify your add or update to specify a job id:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("some-id", () => /* my method */, "*/20 * * * *");
```

followed by

```
RecurringJob.Trigger("some-id");
```

[To run a recurring job now, call the Trigger method.](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html)

UPDATE: How about a delayed job then instead of a recurring job? Your "my method" creates a new delayed job at the end (Recursion), set to run after 20 mins. You will still use the Trigger method for the first run.

Comment: This will make the method run immediately, which is good, but then it will return to its old ways of on the 20 minute mark (00, 20, 40) each hour.

Answer (score 0):

One 'hacky' way of achieving this is to set a [small number of workers](https://www.hangfire.io/features.html).

```
app.UseHangfire(config =>
{
    config.UseServer(2);
});

// or
var server = new BackgroundJobServer(2);
```

Whether you look at this and say 'oh great!' or 'that is a terrible idea' will depend completely on your own usage of Hangfire. If you only run a few things an hour, or every 15 minutes and you find they're 'treading' on each other then this could be a simple solution.

A second way: You could make an async Task and run `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))` to make a short delay. This quite likely could cause your app to shutdown more slowly because it would think you're still running tasks. So I only only using this in an emergency, or if you're ok with the consequences.

Hopefully Hangfire will support this in a more organized way at some point.

Comment: Note the jobs (now) support CancellationTokens, so you can pass that to the Delay which should take care of the shutdown.